# Parse api's saveInBackground not working in Swift 3

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, swift3, xcode8

I'm testing my parse code on Heroku because of parse.com's shutdown. In Swift 3, **saveInBackgroundWithBlock** has been renamed to **saveInBackground**, so I updated that syntax in my code as well as the 'NS' prefix issue. But an error still remains. As a learner, I can't possibly take care of this further. I want a kind person to help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let object = PFObject(className: "testObject")
        object["name"] = "Bill"
        object["lastname"] = "Alexander"
        object.saveInBackground(block: { (success, error) in
            if success {
                print("Saved in server")
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
        })
}
```

Here is also my screenshot:

['Expected declaration' error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lL76.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost there, The syntax is just slightly incorrect. Also check against the error for any issues.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

            override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()

                let object = PFObject(className: "testObject")
                object["name"] = "Bill"
                object["lastname"] = "Alexander"
                object.saveInBackground { (success, error) -> Void in
                     if error == nil {
                        print("Saved in server")
                    } else {
                        print(error!)
                    }


               }
            }
```